# Firebase AppCheck not working with PlayIntegrity provider

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

I have followed the appcheck setup [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider) for android, and have run into the following problem when trying to get a token from within the app:

`FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed`

when invoking appcheck as s follows:

```kotlin
//initialize on app-start
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(applicationContext)
FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance().apply {
    installAppCheckProviderFactory(
        PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
    )
}

//get token to then use in backend calls
firebaseAppCheck
    .getAppCheckToken(true)
    .addOnCompleteListener {
        //do something with the token
    }
```

As HTTP 403 (forbidden) suggests a misconfiguration of access-rights, I have double checked the configuration as the documentation suggests, and wanted to narrow-down where the problem could lie, when I found myself in the following (weird) situation:

- Changing from `PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory`to `SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory`, I was able to retrieve a token, leading me to the assumption that not the `firebase` access, but rather the `app integrity` access fails.
- Using the `IntegrityManager` from the play-integrity android library in a standalone fashion, **I am also able to get a token**, which seems to conflict with my assumption so far...

I am using

Appcheck: `com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity:16.1.0`

Play-integrity standalone: `com.google.android.play:integrity:1.0.2`

Anyone know what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not distributed via Google Play, the [Play Integrity Provider does not work with your Firebase app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider#:%7E:text=Play%20Integrity%20provider%20only%20supports%20Android%20apps%20distributed%20by%20Google%20Play). Another issue may be that the registered SHA-256 key may not be the same that Google Play is using to sign your app. I would validate that you are using the app from the play store with the Google Play Signed SHA-256 fingerprint.

Comment: It is also mentioned in the official documentation that to use Play Integrity's off-play features, custom app check provider can be implemented. Unfortunately, there is no proper sample code available for that. May you kindly mention a link where we can find a guidance for the code to implement Play Integrity App Check as custom provider for apps *NOT* distributed through Google Play?

Comment: Is this still the case? We're using Firebase App Distribution prior to release to distribute to internal testers. How does one test/use Firebase AppCheck prior to release?

Comment: @nsk - Use the internal test track from Google Play. This will still ensure that the app is Play Signed. Firebase App Distro should use Google Play under the hood iirc

Comment: I would also like to know the work-around for this.  We have a test environment to use for testing and allows us to create font-end and back-end changes that are not ready for production.  The internal test track does not satisfy this, as I don't want the possibility of promoting an app that pointed to test data.  Is there a way to use Firebase App Distribution and AppCheck for an app that is not yet published in the Play Store?

Comment: @TheMason - you could always use a custom provider with a lower tier of restrictions for test apps.